# How does it come that my gremlin query delivers two different results?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I needed to write a query which merges two vertices together with all the outgoing edges and properties. For the development process I used gremlify and following testdata:

```
g.addV("TopVertex").property('id', 4713).property('testProperty1','testProperty1').as('vertex1')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C1').as('C1')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C2').as('C2')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C3').as('C3')
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex1').to('C1').property('ordinal',1)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex1').to('C2').property('ordinal',2)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex1').to('C3').property('ordinal',3)

.addV("TopVertex").property('id', 4713).property('testProperty2','testProperty2').as('vertex2')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C4').as('C4')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C5').as('C5')
.addV("SubVertex").property('name','C6').as('C6')
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex2').to('C4').property('ordinal',4)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex2').to('C5').property('ordinal',5)
.addE("splitsInto").from('vertex2').to('C6').property('ordinal',6)
```

I came up with this solution:

```
g.addV("MergedVertex").property('id', 4713).as('mergedVertex').
V().hasLabel("TopVertex").has('id', 4713).as('oldVertices').
       outE().as('oldEdges').
       inV().as('inVertices').
       select('mergedVertex').
       addE('splitsInto').to('inVertices').as('newEdges').
       sideEffect(select('oldEdges').properties().
                  unfold().as('props').
                  select('newEdges').
                  property(select('props').key(), select('props').value())).
       select('oldVertices').drop()
```

When I executed this query on gremlify everything did run perfectly. But when I executed this query on my neptune database (running engine version 1.1.1.0) only the first edge property got copied. With this I mean the property "ordinal 1" and "ordinal 4" is present, the rest disappeared.

I would have expected that the result is the same. Can someone explain to me why the results differ?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the differences you describe using TinkerGraph and Amazon Neptune. This will take some investigation.  I will report back with any discoveries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fairly in-depth analysis of what is going on here, the difference in results is due to the way that each system is processing the `drop` step. The root cause is that in both cases the `drop` step is evaluated in a lazy rather than greedy fashion.  You can see the same results on TinkerGraph if you disable `LazyBarrierStrategy`. For example:

```java
gremlin> g.withoutStrategies(LazyBarrierStrategy.class).addV("MergedVertex").property('id', 4713).as('mergedVertex').
......1> V().hasLabel("TopVertex").has('id', 4713).as('oldVertices').
......2>        outE().as('oldEdges').
......3>        inV().as('inVertices').
......4>        select('mergedVertex').
......5>        addE('splitsInto').to('inVertices').as('newEdges').
......6>        sideEffect(select('oldEdges').properties().
......7>                   unfold().as('props').
......8>                   select('newEdges').
......9>                   property(select('props').key(), select('props').value())).
.....10>        select('oldVertices').drop()

gremlin> g.E()
==>e[102][100-splitsInto->91]
==>e[103][100-splitsInto->79]

gremlin> g.E().valueMap()
==>[ordinal:4]
==>[ordinal:1]
```

Even more subtly, TinkerGraph is working in some ways more by chance. If there were more than 2500 results flowing into the `drop` you would see similar behavior on TinkerGraph as you see on Neptune even without disabling `LazyBarrierStrategy`. This is because the default maximum barrier size in TinkerGraph is 2500.

For now, on Neptune you could achieve the results you want by adding a `barrier` step to the query. For example:

```java
g.addV("MergedVertex").property('id', 4713).as('mergedVertex').
V().hasLabel("TopVertex").has('id', 4713).as('oldVertices').
       outE().as('oldEdges').
       inV().as('inVertices').
       select('mergedVertex').
       addE('splitsInto').to('inVertices').as('newEdges').
       sideEffect(select('oldEdges').properties().
                  unfold().as('props').
                  select('newEdges').
                  property(select('props').key(), select('props').value())).
       select('oldVertices').barrier(100000).drop()
```

This is something that needs some additional discussion within the TinkerPop community as to how best to adjust this behavior. For now, the `barrier` step should provide a solution.